# Getting null values even that in scrapy shell the value isn't null

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm getting null values even seeing that in scrapy shell  the value isnt null

I've tried to scrapy this link: `https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductChemicalPropertiesCB2909992_EN.htm`
and to get the product name i'm using:

```
response.css('.ProdSupplierGN_ProductA_2 .td1+ td a::text').get()
```

but when i saw the output `scrapy.json` my data was:

```
{
   "link":"https://www.chemicalbook.com/ProductChemicalPropertiesCB2909992_EN.htm",
   "name":null,
   "cas":null,
   "synomym":[

   ],
   "molecular_formula":null,
   "molecular_weight":null,
   "einecs":null,
   "product_categories":[

   ],
   "melting_point":null,
   "vapor_pressure":[

   ],
   "form":null,
   "henry_law_constant":null,
   "stability":null,
   "inchikey":null,
   "hazard_codes":null,
   "risk_statements":null,
   "safety_statements":null,
   "wgk":null,
   "tsca":null,
   "packing_group":null,
   "hs_code":null,
   "hazardous_substance_data":null,
   "chemical_properties":null,
   "definition":null,
   "air_and_water_reactions":null,
   "general_description":null,
   "reactivity_profile":null,
   "fire_hazard":null
}
```

```py
    def parse_chemi_link(self, response):
        items = ChemibookItem()

        #------------------------------BASIC INFORMATION    
        link = response.url
        name = response.css('.ProdSupplierGN_ProductA_2 .td1+ td a::text').get()
        synomym = response.css('.ProdSupplierGN_ProductA_2+ .ProdSupplierGN_ProductA_2 td+ td font::text').getall()
        items['link'] = link
        items['name'] = name
        items['synomym'] = synomym
        yield items
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use XPath expression for this task (because you can refer to the anchor text):

```
response.xpath('string(//td[.="Product Name:"]/following-sibling::td[1])').get()
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I will try using xpath, but one thing that i've noticed is the items.py: when i use items with the spider, the result is this stackovpost, but when i dont use the result come ok. So now i'm using the yield {'link':link, 'name':name...} to compare the results

Comment: UPDATE: the problem was not with items.py. I think the problem is with proxies. i'm rotating proxies to do not get blocked so some of them already dead. It means that when i try to connect in to the page, the request can't happen.